# C# DateTime.Parse Error

Tags: c#, datetime

Anyone have any idea why this fails? I was able to work around it with ParseExact, but I would like to understand why it is failing.

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Parse("Dec 24  17:45");
```

Dates < "Dec 24" work fine. Dates >= Dec 24 fail with this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

EDIT:
Thanks to Habib for noticing even when I didn't get an error it was not the result I was expecting. So be careful with the DateTime.Parse when not used with supported formats!

Here is what I did to fix the issue. I only have to handle two different formats. The current year would be "MMM dd HH:mm" otherwise it would be "MMM dd yyyy"

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(inDateTime, "MMM dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces,out outDateTime))
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(inDateTime, "MMM dd yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out outDateTime))
    {
        //Handle failure to Parse
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you tried to exec?

Comment: That's a good question.

Comment: @A.Abramov -- The OP included pretty much all that is needed.

Comment: Something related to the missing year I suppose.

Comment: @Steve -- yeah, but why does it assume the current year up to the 24th?

Comment: In any case the conversion of `Dec 23 17:45` (in my locale) gives back a date like `23/02/2015 23:17:00`

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture tells me ID=1033 and name "English (United States)"

Comment: You can see that your string isn't one of the "forms" allowed for `Parse`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#StringToParse

Comment: @wsware You should show the code which you used with `ParseExact` so that future readers of your question can see how the parsing should be done ;)

Comment: `ParseExact` is also more performant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Dates < "Dec 24" work fine. Dates >= Dec 24 fail with this error

`DateTime.Parse` uses the [standard formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for parsing date and the reason it is failing for Day >= 24, is that it is considering **that part as an hour part instead of day part** as you assumed.

Since allowed hour part could be between 0 to 23, it works fine for those *dates. (It is not considered a day part)*

Also it is ignoring `Dec` part and considering current date for that part.

Consider the example below:

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Parse("Dec 22 17:45");
```

It returns:

```
test = {23/02/2015 10:17:00 PM}
```

Look at the time part it is set to 22:17 or 10:17 PM

Comment: FYI it doesn't actually "work" for 0-23. For `Dec 23  17:45`, it comes back out as `2/23/2015 11:17:00 PM`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/WyVMRl

Comment: @tnw, I meant the hour part is allowed to have values from 0 to 23.

Comment: Ah yeah fair enough, just wanted to make sure that distinction was made.

Comment: Thanks. I failed to notice how wrong the result was when I did get one. I had set my system clock back to that date and got a correct date since Parse uses the current date/time for unknow information.

Answer (score -2):

The DateTime format that you are passing is not valid. I believe the problem is that you aren't supplying a year for the date portion. Here is an example of an accepted DateTime:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("Dec 24 2015 17:45");
```

Comment: I understand after rereading the question. Sorry I jumped the gun, I was just excited to start helping out and learning more myself :)